# Javascript images array preload speed and remove from memory

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, memory, preload

I have a asp.net MVC application where I display a number of image in a view, the number of these images rang between 100 to 2500 per group.  On the view I preload the images for each group, then I select a different group from a dropdownlist, this will refresh the page.  First preload works great, however, when I change the group it is very slow.  The reference to these images are in a MS SQL database, the list of images for a particular gorup comes throught the controller (C#).  Here is the Javascript I am using:

```
        var impath = $("#ImagePath").val();
        var im = $("#ImageName").val();

        var images = null;
        var images = [];
        var tochar = $("#lastchar").val();


        function preload_images() {

            var i;
            for (i = tochar; i < sl; i++) {
                images[i] = new Image();
                var name = impath.toString() + im.toString() + i;

            }
        }
```

My question is there is a way to speed up the preload process, and do I need to remove the preloaded images from the memory before loading the next group and how can I delete them, I used images=null, is this is the right way.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure if I read your question correctly - you're preloading up to 2500 images and you're wondering why it's slow?

Comment: I just would like to know if there is a better way to preload the images and how to remove the preloaded files from memory.

Comment: @user373721: you cannot remove them. It is what browser handles automatically

Comment: Note that the preloaded images array must remain in memory until all the images load, otherwise they won't all load (especially if there are 2,500 of them). So it's common to add them to a global object or array that stays in memory. Oh, and declaring and initialising `images` twice is redundant, just use `var images = [];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to handle that many images would be using sprites.  With sprites, you load one larger image that contains many, many smaller images.  Since loading a single image is lot, lot faster in the browser than loading a lot of small images, your preloading can be a lot faster.  In fact, you could literally just preload one image that contained a whole block of your sub-images.

Then, when you want to display one of those images, you display only a clipped portion of the image.  There are a number of ways to do that display, but a common way is creating an object of the desired cell size and displaying the larger image as the background with the appropriate offset to line up with the desired part of the larger image.

Here's a useful reference on CSS and sprites: http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/

You do have to create the appropriate sprites on the server side to use this technique.

---

In answer to some of your other questions.

No, you can't speed them up any more other than loading fewer images (as suggested above) or reducing the size of each image.  The browser will only make N image requests at a time (likely to avoid overloading servers) over the network so the rest will be queued up until one finishes and then the next request will be made, etc...

You can release images from memory by just making sure that you aren't holding a reference to them any more.  That way, the browser garbage collector will clean up the Image() objects that you had created.  In your code setting `images = null` or `images = []` will accomplish that as long as those Image() objects aren't referenced anywhere else.  The images will still remain in the browser's cache and will still essentially be preloaded (they won't have to be loaded over the network if referenced again).

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to explain.  The sprites solution is great, except in my case I am using DICOM images.  Thank you again for your answer.